# How to use a matrix to store a vector in each element

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have not seen this in MATLAB. Suppose I have

```
V1 = [1 0],  V2 = [0 1]
```

I want to create a matrix such that the matrix has to be

```
[[1 0] [0 1]      
 [0 1] [0 2]]
```

i.e., the first row and column are `[V1 V2]`, element `(2,2)` of the matrix is `[0 1]+[0 1]=[0 2]`

So index `(1,1)` of the matrix should be `[1 0]`, index `(1,2)` of matrix should be `[0 1]`.

Is there any way I can implement this in MATLAB?

Comment: one matrix element can only contains one value, not two.

Comment: why can't you just create a matrix A = `[V1 V2;V2 2*V2]` ?

Comment: @obchardon Yes, I can do that; however, if I want to find (1,1) of A, it will not tell me 1 0. Kronecker product also results in the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix can only contain one value per element. Here are 3 options for how you could get close to what you've described:

1. You could create a 4*4 matrix like so:

   ```
   V1 = [1 0]; V2 = [0 1];
   M = [V1, V2; V2, 2*V2];
   ```

   And then create a shorthand function to index this in blocks of 2

   ```
   Mb = @(r,c) M( r, 2*c-1+[0,1] );

   Mb(1,1); % = [1 0]
   Mb(1,2); % = [0 1]
   Mb(2,2); % = [0 2]
   ```

   Note that this doesn't work for assignment back to `M` in blocks of 2, just for reading the value.

---

2. Alternatively, you could use a cell array

   ```
   C = {V1, V2; V2, 2*V2};
   ```

   Now you can index this how you want, but it won't behave as a single matrix, and you can't do numerical operations on the whole cell array

   ```
   C{2,2}; % = [2, 2], note the curly brace indexing
   ```

---

3. A third option would be to make your matrix 3D

   ```
   V1 = reshape( V1, 1, 1, [] );
   V2 = reshape( V2, 1, 1, [] );
   M3D = [V1, V2; V2, 2*V2];
   ```

   Now you can index in the 3rd dimension

   ```
   M3D(2,2,:); % = [0 2], but size [1,1,2]. Could reshape(M3D(2,2,:),1,[]) to get a row.
   ```

Comment: Almost there, Thanks!